# Create a field that assigns a value depending how many layers it intersects

Tags: field-calculator, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I'm trying to create a new field in my attribute table that can assign a value to the polygon depending on how many layers of my buffers it intersects.

So i have a base layer called `"properties"` and other layers from which i have created different buffers `"transport" "green areas" "city center"`

In the `"properties"` layer I want to add a new field to the attribute table assigning a different value depending how many layers (buffers) the polygon intersects.

For example:

If the polygons in `"properties"` intersects or is contained just `"transport"` = 1

If the polygons in `"properties"` intersects or is contained `"transport"` and `"green areas"` = 2

If the polygons in `"properties"` intersects or is contained `"Transport", "green areas"` and `"city center"` = 3

If the polygons in `"properties"` does not intersect any buffer= 0

Any idea if this can be done? And if yes how can I do it? im quite new to QGIS and im still exploring and learning how all the expressions work.

Answer (score 1):

Use this expression in the **properties** layer to calculate the count of intersecting layers.

```
array_length(
    array:=array_filter(
        -- list of layer names to evaluate if are intersecting "properties layer
        array:=array(
            'transport',
            'green areas',
            'city center'
        ),
        expression:=overlay_intersects(
            layer:=@element
        )
    )
)
```